# Switching DbSet by name

Tags: c#, linq

I've been searching for an answer for hours. I've read many similar posts but still cannot get to the point.
In geolocating an ASPNET MVC website I need to switch between 'n' tables depending on user ip.
All tables have been named 'GeoData_' plus a convenient countryCode suffix (IT, FR, US...). Moreover, as they all contain the same fields, they inherit from the same 'GeoData' interface.

I know I can get needed dbset in the controller this way:

```
string countryTable = "GeoData_" + Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["_country"].Value.ToUpper());

        var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == countryTable);

        DbSet GeoContext = db.Set(type);
```

Now, I simply cannot pass this DbSet as I was used before, that is

```
var searchResult = GeoContext
                    .Where(c => c.PlaceName.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper()))
                    .Select(c => new
                    {
                        PlaceName = c.PlaceName,
                        PostalCode = c.PostalCode,
                        GeoDataID = c.ID,
                        Latitude = c.Latitude,
                        Longitude = c.Longitude
                    }
                    )
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderBy(c => (c.PlaceName.ToUpper().IndexOf(term.ToUpper())))
                    .ToList();
```

because model's fields (c.Placename etc...) can no more be referenced to GeoContext.

I suppose one way could be using System.Linq.Dynamic and changing the entire query consequently.
Is there a way to take advantage of all tables inheriting from same interface to get a better workaround?

Comment: Are you able to change the tables in any way?

Comment: Do you really need separate tables for each country code? Why not just add another column (e.g. `LanguageID`) and use a single table?

Comment: Shouldn't be doing that, if you need to split the table up, let sql server take care of it.

Comment: David: Hundreds of tables, one per every world's nation, everyone containing hundred of thousans of geolocations data. No, I cannot use a single table.

Keith: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am here to learn so, just to be sure, are you really suggesting the best option is to use and maintain a single table with tens of millions records?

Answer (score 0):

try defining the DbSet class explicitly
like

```
DbSet<Class> GeoContext = db.Set<Class>(type);
```

i`m guessing you have this Class defined somewhere in your code